# css not loading correctly after javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

When the user clicks on the button with `id=cancel`, they are redirected to index.php.

```
$('#cancel').click(function() {
   if(changes > 0){
      $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
   }else{
      window.location.href = "../index.php/";
   }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when they are redirected, all I'm seeing is the un-styled index.php page.  When I clicked on the style.css link in firebug, it is just showing index.php.  Why would the browser be loading index.php as the stylesheet?  This happens in FF, Chrome, Safari.

Comment: Do you mean to be redirecting to the folder named "index.php" or do you mean to redirect to the file "index.php"? Because "/index.php/" is looking for a folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Servers will serve up the same content for `/index.php` and `/index.php/` but relative URIs using them as base URIs will be different.

You are probably finding that you are loading `/index.php/style.css` (which will have the same content as `/index.php` if the script doesn't special case it) when you want `/style.css`.

I suggest:

- Using URIs relative to the site root (i.e. which start with `/`) so that they function no matter how many levels deep you are
- Linking to `../index.php` or `../` instead of `../index.php/`